# Get changesets for workitem through code in Visual Studio 2017+

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm trying to get all Changesets for a specific WorkItem using the new Http method.

I used to be able to do it this way but everything broke when 2017 came out.

```
    workItem.Links.Cast<Link>().Where(x => x.ArtifactLinkType.Name == 
    "Fixed in Changeset")
```

I see Links in WorkItemTrackingHttpClient but none of them seem like what I'm looking for.

I can do it the other way and get all workitems from a Changeset using TfvcHttpClient but that's not helpful. Trying to iterate through every Changeset to find the WorkItem I'm looking for would be very slow and inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as soon as I post my question I always seeem to find the answer. Looked for hours last night. Need WorkItemExpand.All or WorkItemExpand.Relations. Once you pass that in it lists all artifacts.

```
        string collectionUri = "My_TFS_Server";
        string projectName = "My_Project_Name";
        int myWorkItemID = 7000;
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssCredentials());
        WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();


        var wi =  witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(myWorkItemID ,null,null,WorkItemExpand.All).Result;
```